Integration of the square of the sum of two error functions
This is more of sharing an answer than a question.
In the field of scalar diffusion and all physical applications that exploit analogy with scalar diffusion, such as the dispersion of bluff-body wakes normal to the flow direction, the solution of the one-dimensional diffusion equation from an initial concentration region $-h<x<h$ is important and takes the form (Crank, 1979)
\begin{equation}
    C(x,t) = A \left(\textrm{erf}\left(\frac{h-x}{2\sqrt{D t}}\right) + \textrm{erf}\left(\frac{h+x}{2\sqrt{D t}}\right) \right), 
\end{equation}
where $C$ is the concentration of the diffusing matter, $t$ is time, $D$ is a diffusion coefficient, $A$ is a constant, and erf is the error function defined as
\begin{equation}
    \textrm{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int\limits_0^{z} e^{-s^2}~ds.
\end{equation}
The constant $A$ is typically obtained from conservation of mass. However, in some applications the conservation of momentum is relevant taking the form
\begin{equation}
    \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} C(C_0-C)~dx = 2C_0^2 h c_f,
\end{equation}
where $C_0$ is the initial concentration and $c_f$ is an arbitrary momentum coefficient. This condition involves an integral of $C^2$ which can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
      \mathcal{M}(a) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
    \left(\textrm{erf}(a-\eta) + \textrm{erf}(a+\eta)\right)^2~d\eta,
\end{equation}
where $a = h/(2\sqrt{Dt})$ and $\eta=x/(2\sqrt{Dt})$.
I could not find an exact solution to the integral $\mathcal{M}(a)$ in integration tables. However, it turns out that solving for $\mathcal{M}(a)$ is not complicated if one makes use of differentiating under the integral sign. As such, I wanted to share with you the solution to $\mathcal{M}(a)$ in case anyone needs it.

The integrated quantity is even, and hence we can consider only half the $\eta$ range:
\begin{equation}
      \mathcal{M}(a) = 2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}
    \left(\textrm{erf}(a-\eta) + \textrm{erf}(a+\eta)\right)^2~d\eta.
\label{eqn:w2}
  \end{equation}
By differentiating $\mathcal{M}(a)$ we have
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
    \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}\frac{d\mathcal{M}}{da} & = 
    %\underbrace{
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a+\eta) e^{-(a+\eta)^2}~d\eta
    +
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a-\eta) e^{-(a-\eta)^2}~d\eta \,
    %}_{=\,0}
    + \\  & 
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a+\eta) e^{-(a-\eta)^2}~d\eta  
    + 
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a-\eta) e^{-(a+\eta)^2}~d\eta. 
\end{split}
\label{eqn:dgda}
\end{equation}
Since the error function is odd, the first two terms on the right-hand side can be re-written as
\begin{equation}
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a+\eta) e^{-(a+\eta)^2}~d\eta
    +
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a-\eta) e^{-(a-\eta)^2}~d\eta
    =
    \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a+\eta) e^{-(a+\eta)^2}~d\eta = 0,
\end{equation}
which is the integration of an odd function along the real number line, and hence it vanishes. Similarly, the remaining two terms on the right-hand side are
\begin{equation}
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a+\eta) e^{-(a-\eta)^2}~d\eta  
    + 
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a-\eta) e^{-(a+\eta)^2}~d\eta
    =
    \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(a+\eta) e^{-(a-\eta)^2}~d\eta.
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}\frac{d\mathcal{M}}{da} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \textrm{erf}(\xi) e^{-(2a-\xi)^2}~d\xi,
\label{eqn:dgda2} 
\end{equation}
where $\xi = a+\eta$. The solution to this integral is $\sqrt{\pi}\, \textrm{erf}(\sqrt{2}a)$, and the main integral $\mathcal{M}(a)$ becomes
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{M}(a) = 8 \int \textrm{erf}(\sqrt{2}a)~ da = 8 \left(a\,\textrm{erf}(\sqrt{2}a) + \frac{e^{-2a^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} + q \right),
\end{equation}
where $q$ is an integration constant that can be obtained from the condition $\mathcal{M}(0) = 0$. This leads to
\begin{equation}
    q=-1/\sqrt{2\pi},
\end{equation}
and hence the analytical solution to the sought integral is
\begin{equation}
    \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
    \left(\textrm{erf}(a-\eta) + \textrm{erf}(a+\eta)\right)^2~d\eta
    =
    8 \left(a\,\textrm{erf}(\sqrt{2}a) + \frac{e^{-2a^2}-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \right).
    \label{eqn:sol}
\end{equation}
I also wrote the derivation in a preprint that I put on ResearchGate (DOI: 10.13140/RG.2.2.27966.09287).
I hope this becomes of help if anyone needs it.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

@ThànhNguyễn Thanks for pointing this out. I included the derivation in my answer above.
